# how could I sort the coordinate of this picture in python?

Tags: python, sorting

I have an image and this image has some bounding boxes with their coordinate, which is top left coordinates.

I got these values now. order is `(3,5), (9,3), (5,7) ,(2,9) ,(4,10) ,(9,9)`

I want to sort the values like the below order from images.
order :

- bounding box1 (3,5),
- bounding box2 (5,7),
- bounding box3 (9,3),
- bounding box4 (2,9),
- bounding box5 (4,10),
- bounding box6 (9,9).

I tried to find rule of this value but it was failed for sorting

could you please help me?[image]

Comment: Your GSI would be a better resource for such a question than here.

Comment: Where is the code that is not working?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I couldn't understand what is the sorting algorithm, what the condition for a point to be higher or lower than others?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about a specific programming problem.